# How to print object variable?

Tags: objective-c, object, printing

How do I print the value of -> event.latitude = [[values objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];  ?

Below is some of my code:

```
@interface SeismicEvent : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{
  float latitude;
  float longitude;


**This is an object
 SeismicEvent *event;


** This reads in a float

 event.latitude = [[values objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
```

How do I print out event.latitude?

I tried NSString `*str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", event.latitude];`

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should add the objective-C tag to this question.

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon - You can edit his tags (since you're over 500 in reputation).

Comment: Thanks guys , sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.latitude];
```

Notice the format string

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to print it out, why not try:

```
NSLog(@"%f", event.latitude);
```